# Soma PHP e maior número

Tags: php

Estou tentando elaborar um sistema de frete para uma empresa mas estou com um problema. Assim,segue-se:

- o frete em si é calculado pelo sistema dos Correios que acesso por meio de uma API;
- já fiz tudo o que consta no site dos Correios para realizar as consultas para cálculo de frete;

Para a API dos Correios, se fazem necessários a altura, a largura, o peso e o comprimento do produto. Estes valores, por sua vez, são obtidos do banco de dados do cliente de acordo com o produto a que se deseja calcular o frete.

Preciso que o sistema obtenha o maior valor de comprimento e de largura e some a altura e o peso de cada `produto($id)` que contem no carrinho. Preciso que esse cálculo seja feito para, por exemplo, colocar uma caixa em cima da outra e não lado a lado pois as caixas menores sempre serão colocadas, no envio, em cima das maiores. Evita prejuízos para o cliente e fornecedor.

Não consigo pensar em uma maneira de resolver este problema. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Você tem algum problema de programação ou algum código específico que tem dificuldade? Se conseguisse traduzir seu texto em pseudo-código já ajudava...